# jQuery File Upload Success Message

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

i´m setting up the Plugin jQuery File Upload, and i want to pop up a success message, if the upload is complete. There are callback-functions like this:

```
$('#fileupload')
.bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {/* ... */});
```

i think i need this function:

```
.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

but i don´t know where to place this?
Thx 4 your help

Comment: *"where to place this?"* - Most likely on a `<form>` or an `<input type="file">`.

Comment: i´m completely new in this topic, so please, give me a example where to place... :) i got <form> and <input type="file"> elements

Comment: `$('form').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})` or `$(input[type="file"]').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})`

Comment: if my form got an id="fileupload" can i write this:       `<script>$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data)      {alert("hallo")});</script>`